# Set fill settings for desktop background image Ubuntu budgie 17.04

Tags: 17.04, budgie

I changed my background desktop image today but I cannot find any options to change it to fill or span the screen like this:

[image: Appearance]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For 17.04 the default picture options for wallpapers can be set via the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'none'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'wallpaper'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'centered'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'scaled'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'stretched'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'spanned'
```

To reset back to the default:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using terminal?

Comment: not for the moment in 17.04 - but if some nice person helps us adding to budgie-welcome then we can create a nice "tweak tool".

Comment: does not work on 22.04 ... any updated suggestions

Answer (score 9):

Late to answer on this one, but for anyone who is interested.

You can also install the `gnome-tweak-tool`, which is now called `gnome-tweaks` as of 18.04.  You to the tab *Appearance* you will then find the setting under *Adjustment*.

`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

or if you are version 18.04 or later.

`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Though, I can't find anything to repeat the background. I use odd size displays in different orientations and was trying to find a solution for a background that would fit without scaling